# Write .3gp file on sd card

Tags: android, file-io, android-external-storage

I have .3gp audio file which is stored in SD Card.I want to copy that file into another folder of sd card.I have googled a lot about it but didn't get any working idea.Please help me if anyone knows.The code I have tried till now is given below:

```
private void save(File file_save) {

    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/RecordedAudio";
    File file_dir = new File(file_path);
    if (file_dir.exists()) {
        file_dir.delete();
    }
    file_dir.mkdirs();
    File file_audio = new File(file_dir, "audio"
            + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".3gp");
    try {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
        out.writeObject(file_save);
        out.close();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file_audio);

        byte[] buffer = bos.toByteArray();
        fos.write(buffer);

        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is always create a new file with the size of 100.Thanks in advance...
The code when i call this save() method is:

```
 mFileFirst = new File(mFileName);//mFileName is the path of sd card where .3gp file is located
    save(mFileFirst);
```

Comment: you didn't loop for next buffer ?

Comment: Have you tried using FileUtils from apache commons? `http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyFile(java.io.File, java.io.File)`

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9a7debe5857ffc7c71cfc4082b1b6d72a5cf81cd/core/java/android/os/FileUtils.java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8087226/copying-a-file-to-from-external-storage

Comment: Thanks..@Amigable Clark Kant...It works perfect...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void save(File file_save) {
    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/RecordedAudio";
    File file_dir = new File(file_path);
    if (file_dir.exists()) {
        file_dir.delete();
    }
    file_dir.mkdirs();
    File file_audio = new File(file_dir, "audio"
            + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".3gp");
    try {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file_save);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file_audio);

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        int total = 0;
        while ((len = fis.read(buf)) > 0) {
            total += len;
            fos.write(buf, 0, len);
            // Flush the stream once every so often
            if (total > (20 * 1024)) {
                fos.flush();
            }
        }
        fos.flush();
        fis.close();
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```